# Monotorrent UDP error

Tags: c#, torrent, monotorrent

I tried to torrent files with this void:

```
        public void DownloadTorrent(string path)
        {
            Torrent torrent = Torrent.Load(path);

            Console.WriteLine(torrent.Files[0]);
            TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, savePath, new TorrentSettings());
            engine.Register(manager);
            manager.HashCheck(true);
            manager.Start();
        }
```

but every time I load a torrent file, I get this error:

```
Unsupported protocol udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce
Unsupported protocol udp://tracker.istole.it:80/announce
```

does someone knows how to solve this

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTorrent hasn't seen a commit in [almost three years](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/commits/master) and even before that you can see that it was very sparsely worked on after 2010. It won't have all the nice features that a modern torrent client will have, just saying.

Anyway, the UDP Tracker Protocol was [first published in 2008](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) so it's a fair chance that there actually is some support. Looking through their commits on github shows us that [c900c7c](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/commit/c900c7c549340f4f97cb191325292cd10cd96ea4) actually added udp tracker support back in 2009. A quick check in [TrackerFactory.cs](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/blob/master/src/MonoTorrent/MonoTorrent.Client/Tracker/TrackerFactory.cs) also shows that the support still is there.

There is however a [pull request regarding the udp tracker protocol](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/pull/37) that hasn't been merged (and probably never will) so I'd say that your best bet would be to clone or fork the repository (or one of the [many other forks](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/network)) and build it yourself with that patch added.